# C++ pointer of one type or another?

Tags: object, pointers, types

I have a program that solves PDEs in big grids working in C, but want to port it to C++ to learn object oriented programming.

My problem is that I have two data structures, lets call them *Class1* and *Class2*. To make things simple lets assume that *Class1* contains two doubles (*a* and *b*) and *Class2* contains four doubles (*a,b,c* and *d*).

Now, at runtime I want to generate a dynamic array of some sort that will hold one class **OR** the other depending on the conditions of the PDE.

Something like:

`if (PDEtype == 1)    pointer = new Class1[n]`

```
else              pointer = new Class2[n]
```

Then after that I will need to access *pointer* with something like: `pointer[2].a = 1.0` or `pointer[4].d = 10.0` etc.

A union will not work because I need to store the lowest amount of memory. (I will be working with big problems of possibly millions of points)

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The problem is that there must always be some way to identify which class you are working with. One way would be a common attribute (e.g. type) that identifies the type you are working with. This is not considered good OOP, however. Another way is via virtual methods (polymorphism). Both of these increase the size of the object. If you are concerned about data density (millions of points), you should just stick with C, since C++ OOP will not provide any added benefit. If you do go with OOP, study up on inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: I think this is a classic case of "describe your problem, not the first step *you* decided to take".

Answer (score 0):

If your `Class2` is actually derived from `Class1`, you can have an array of `Class1*`'s. If not, I'd base both `Class1` and `Class2` off a common base class, and had an array of `BaseClass*`'s.

Of course, you need some way to know what's the actual content of the entry (which is better done in C++ with virtual functions, if applicable).

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for the answer. 
I tried this. I derived Class2 from Class1 and generated a dynamic array of Class1's, but when I try to access data from Class2, the compiler says `class Class1’ has no member named ‘xxxx’ (one of the variables from Class2 but not in Class1)

Comment: well, you need some way to know which kind of data is there. either you store that information separately, or include into the structure itself. or you can actually two separate arrays. the question is, why do you need to access the data "manually"? why not just create a virtual method which will do it for you? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

what you have is pretty close actually. the problem is that you will need to create the pointer beforehand and THEN call new Class1[n]. your problem seems to be needing to figure out how to declare the pointer beforehand.

there are two options that i can think of:

1) don't worry about declaring two different pointer types. declare ONE pointer type (in this case it would make sense to have this be Class2 - since Class1 can be thought of as a "subset" of Class1) and then just declare any unused values in Class2 to some specified value signifying that they are unused.

2) i'm not even quite sure if this technique is correct, but there is definitely something along these lines that will work: declare pointer to be of type Void*. you will also need to define ptr1 and ptr2 to point to types of Class1 and Class2 respectively. you will want your Void* pointer to actually point to the class you are defining, then create a function to cast this void* pointer to type ptr1 (a pointer to a Class1 type) or ptr (a pointer to a Class2 type).

this is much like creating a void* (a pointer to a type void) and then casting it as an integer if your memory location actually contains ints. you can then treat this cast as a pointer to an integer.

finally, you say "pointer[2].a = 1.0" and "pointer[4].d = 10.0" in your example. are you creating an array of classes? if you want your pointer to point to one class, then you will end up using "pointer.a" and "pointer.d", right?